# Angular 5 not sending header

Tags: angular, angular-httpclient

I've trawled through loads of posts but can't quite find my issue with the header not being passed in the get request:

```
return this.httpClient.get(this.parseUrl(controller), {
  headers: new HttpHeaders({'Authorization': 'bearer ' + this.authService.getToken()}),
  params: this.parseURLData(data)
})
  .timeout(this.serverTimeout);
```

So the request runs, the params are added but the headers are missing? All i get in the console, is:

```
Accept:*/*
Accept-Encoding:gzip, deflate
Accept-Language:en-GB,en-US;q=0.9,en;q=0.8
Access-Control-Request-Headers:authorization
Access-Control-Request-Method:GET
Connection:keep-alive
Host:h98t5z1
Origin:http://localhost:4200
User-Agent:Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/64.0.3282.186 Safari/537.36
```

I have also tried this notation for the headers but still empty:

```
let headers = new HttpHeaders().set('header1', hvalue1); 
headers = headers.append('header2', hvalue2);
```

Package.json

```
"dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "^5.2.0",
    "@angular/common": "^5.2.0",
    "@angular/compiler": "^5.2.0",
    "@angular/core": "^5.2.0",
    "@angular/forms": "^5.2.0",
    "@angular/http": "^5.2.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^5.2.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^5.2.0",
    "@angular/router": "^5.2.0",
    "bootstrap-css-only": "^4.0.0",
    "core-js": "^2.4.1",
    "moment": "^2.17.1",
    "roboto-fontface": "^0.6.0",
    "rxjs": "^5.5.6",
    "web-animations-js": "^2.3.1",
    "zone.js": "^0.8.19"
}
```

The request works in postman as the header exists.

Any ideas?

Comment: Are you sure this are the headers of the GET request? (It looks like the preflight OPTIONS request)

Comment: `Access-Control-Request-Method:GET`. I think it's the GET request.

Comment: I also think it's the OPTIONS request. Do you get any error server-side? If yes, it's probably misconfigured since browsers will NOT send custom headers like Authorization in the preflight request

Comment: You were right these were the OPTIONS and was getting blocked because of my domain, please see my answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/49420701/1818048

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was switching between Android and Chrome app. Android requires the name of my machine on the network and Chrome doesn't work with this but works with localhost. Changing my URL to use localhost in Chrome did the trick.

Answer (score 0):

For me, work like this

I hope to help you with this code

```
public getUsers(): Observable<User[]> {

    let headers = new Headers();
    headers.append('x-access-token', this.auth.getCurrentUser().token);

    return this.http.get(Api.getUrl(Api.URLS.getUsers), {
      headers: headers
    })
      .map((response: Response) => {
        let res = response.json();

        if (res.StatusCode === 1) {
          this.auth.logout();
        } else {
          return res.StatusDescription.map(user=> {
            return new User(user);
          });
        }
      });
  }
```